# How to print output in table format in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to shell scripting.. I want to disribute all the data of a file in a table format and redirect the output into another file.

I have below input file `File.txt`

```
Fruit_label:1 Fruit_name:Apple
Color:Red
Type: S
No.of seeds:10
Color of seeds :brown
Fruit_label:2 fruit_name:Banana
Color:Yellow
Type:NS
```

I want it to looks like this

`Fruit_label| Fruit_name |color| Type |no.of seeds |Color of seeds`

```
1 |   apple |   red |  S |  10 |   brown 
2 |   banana|   yellow |  NS
```

I want to read all the data line by line  from text file and make the headerlike fruit_label,fruit_name,color,type, no.of seeds, color of seeds and then print all the assigned value in rows.All the above data is different for different fruits for ex. banana dont have seeds so want to keep its row value as blank ..

Can anyone help me here.

Comment: What have you tried? `awk` is the proper tool, though you can use a combination of others that won't be as efficient, but for a few thousand inputs or less, it won't much matter. For larger data sets (hundreds of thousands of records+) `awk` will be orders of magnitude faster than other solutions.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, is a *"Decorate & Process"* approach. What is *"Decorate & Process"*? To *Decorate* is to take the text you have and decorate it with another separator to make field-splitting easier -- like in your case your fields can contain included whitespace along with the `':'` separator between the field-names and values. With your inconsistent whitespace around `':'` -- that makes it a nightmare to process ... simply.

So instead of worrying about what the separator is, think about "What should the fields be?" and then add a new separator (*Decorate*) between the fields and then *Process* with `awk`.

Here `sed` is used to *Decorate* your input with `'|'` as separators (a second call eliminates the `'|'` after the last field) and then a simpler `awk` process is used to `split()` the fields on `':'` to obtain the field-name and field-value where the field-value is simply printed and the field-names are stored in an array. When a duplicate field-name is found -- it is uses as `seen` variable to designate the change between records, e.g.

```
sed -E 's/([^:]+:[[:blank:]]*[^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]*/\1|/g' file | 
sed 's/|$//' |
awk '
  BEGIN { FS = "|" }
  {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      if (split ($i, parts, /[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*/)) {
        if (! n || parts[1] in fldnames) {
          printf "%s %s", n ? "\n" : "", parts[2]
          delete fldnames
          n = 1
        }
        else
          printf " | %s", parts[2]
        fldnames[parts[1]]++
      }
    }
  }
  END { print "" }
'
```

**Example Output**

With your input in `file` you would have:

```
 1 | Apple | Red | S | 10 | brown
 2 | Banana | Yellow | NS
```

You will also see a *"Decorate-Sort-Undecorate"* used to sort data on a new non-existent columns of values by *"Decorating"* your data with a new last field, sorting on that field, and then *"Undecorating"* to remove the additional field when sorting is done. This allow sorting by data that may be the sum (or combination) of any two columns, etc...

Comment: Happy New Year..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.  It is a new year gift, usually you have to demonstrate what you have tried so far and we help you, not do it for you.

**Disclaimer** some guru will probably come up with a simpler awk version, but this works.

**File script.awk**

```
# Remove space prefix
function ltrim(s) { sub(/^[ \t\r\n]+/, "", s); return s }
# Remove space suffix
function rtrim(s) { sub(/[ \t\r\n]+$/, "", s); return s }
# Remove both suffix and prefix spaces
function trim(s) { return rtrim(ltrim(s)); }

# Initialise or reset a fruit array
function array_init() {
    for (i = 0; i <= 6; ++i) {
        fruit[i] = ""
    }
}

# Print the content of the fruit
function array_print() {
    # To keep track if something was printed.  Yes, print a carriage return.
    # To avoid printing a carriage return on an empty array.
    printedsomething = 0
    for (i = 0; i <= 6; =+i) {
        # Do no print if the content is empty
        if (fruit[i] != "") {
            printedsomething = 1
            if (i == 1) {
                # The first field must be further split, to remove "Fruit_name"
                # Split on the space
                split(fruit[i], temparr, / /)
                printf "%s", trim(temparr[1])
            }
            else {
                printf " |   %s", trim(fruit[i])
            }
        }
    }
    if ( printedsomething == 1 ) {
        print ""
    }
}

BEGIN {
    FS = ":"
    print "Fruit_label| Fruit_name |color| Type |no.of seeds |Color of seeds"
    array_init()
}

/Fruit_label/ {
    array_print()
    array_init()
    fruit[1] = $2
    fruit[2] = $3
}
/Color:/ {
    fruit[3] = $2
}
/Type/ {
    fruit[4] = $2
}
/No.of seeds/ {
    fruit[5] = $2
}
/Color of seeds/ {
    fruit[6] = $2
}

END { array_print() }
```

---

- To execute, call `awk -f script.awk File.txt`
- `awk` processes a file line per line.  So the idea is to store fruit information into an array.
- Every time the line "Fruit_label:....." is found, print the current fruit and start a new one.
- Since each line is read in sequence, you tell `awk` what to do with each line, based on a pattern.
- The patterns are what are enclosed between `//` characters at the beginning of each section of code.
- Difficulty: since the first line contains 2 information on every fruit, and I cut the lines on `:` char, the Fruit_label will include "Fruit_name".
- I.e.: the first line is cut like this: `$1 = Fruit_label`, `$2 = 1 Fruit_name`, `$3 = Apple`
- This is why the `array_print()` function is so complicated.
- Trim functions are there to remove spaces.
- Like for the Apple, `Type: S` when split on the `:` will result in  `S`

If it meets your requirements, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers to accept it.